# reverse notes order in org mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I make my notes in this order:

```
* FIRST
* SECOND
* THIRD
...
* LAST
```

what I want when I export to html or latex is the reverse order:

```
* LAST
...
* FIRST
```

so

1. is there any way or command to reverse the order in org file directly ?
2. is there any way to reverse the order while I export the org file to html/latex ?

either should be fine I think.

Comment: in http://orgmode.org/worg/org-configs/org-customization-guide.html there is reference to org-reverse-note-order but it doesn't seem to be there in org mode for me, shame as it would be useful

Comment: The https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-11/msg01277.html about org-reverse-note-order

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a predefined command you are looking for. You can implement it by yourself.

If it's a one-time task I would use emacs macro:

You show only top-level headlines. Then you go to the first headline and start macro `C-x (`  .
You select the line `C-SPACE C-n` and you type `C-u M-x prepend-to-register` . `C-u` deletes the line as well. You stop the macro `C-x )`  .

Now you repeat the macro for all top-level headlines `M-0 C-x e`  .

And you insert the register `C-x r i` .

Comment: Thanks, it works as I want. Good to know there is emacs macro and it's so helpful. Same as register. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for evil users:

- Fold all headlines (<kbd>S-TAB</kbd>) and go to the last one (<kbd>G</kbd>)
- <kbd>qq</kbd> Record macro to register `q`
- <kbd>"Pddk</kbd> Append current headline to register `p` and go a line up
- <kbd>q</kbd> Save macro
- <kbd>@q</kbd> and then <kbd>*X*@@</kbd> with X being the number of remaining headlines
- <kbd>"pp</kbd> Paste from register `p`